# как отключить настройки DM у юзера

Tags: linux, unix, администрирование, nvidia, xorg

Здравсвуйте.
Имеется debian like система с дисплей менеджером fly-dm.
Машина с nvidia и двумя мониторами.
Собственно после настройки этих двух мониторов в nvidia-settings и сохранении настроек в xorg.conf

Последующая перезагрузка и логин под рутом дает нужный(ранее настроенный) результат, то же самое происходит и при логине под под пользователем user(созданным при установке системы, не знаю на сколько это важно), а вот при логине под еще одним юзером - tatuk, созданным во время эксплуатации системы, настройки мониторов и разрешение слетают.

Я предполагаю что какие то конфиги этого юзера-tatuk перенастраивают, НО ВОТ КАКИЕ, не подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй убрать `monitors.xml` в `~/.config`.